# How to print Scala's XML output to a Play! view?

Tags: xml, scala, view, playframework, playframework-2.1

I've created some helper classes to provide further functionalities to my views. E.g. I've got a class `Button` that's supposed to render some custom HTML to display a button element. Those classes are written in plain Scala and do not make use of Play's templating files. But of course I still can (and want to) call them like `@Button( "label", ... )` from within my views.

However, the problem I'm facing are my `toString` methods.

```
class Button( val label: String, ... )
{
    override def toString: String =
    {
        <a ...> ... </a>.toString
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this will escape the HTML characters to `&lt;` etc. in the views.

How do I export Scala's XML properly to the Play views? I would like to stick around with the XML and not write them as Strings in first place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't played with Play, but a quick google search came up with this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/WiDo3WJnC9s

> Yes any output will be escaped and wrapped in a play.templates.Html
>   type.
>
> So if you want to control the escaping mechanism, just make your 
>   dynamic expression directly return Html:
>   `@Html("<strong>Do not escape</strong>")`

Wouldn't avoid writing the XML to string first, but I guess that is not the main issue :)

Comment: Thanks, you gave me a hint into the right direction. All I have to do is retuning an Html-object from the companion's apply method. Adding some implicit xmlToString conversion to my helper package keep the code clean.